# MsBuild Package generate a lot of subdirectories

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, msdeploy

I'm trying to create a package with MsBuild for my .NET4.5 framework App.

I execute this msbuild command :

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "C:\ContinuousIntegration\_workspace\SolutionName\src\ProjectName\ProjectName.csproj" 
/T:Package
/p:Configuration="Release",
PackageLocation="C:\ContinuousIntegration\Delivery\ProjectName.zip",
PublishMode="Review",
cfgTplPath="C:\ContinuousIntegration\ConfigurationFiles",
DeployIisAppPath="IisProjectName"
```

The zip is well generated but there are 11 useless subdirectories.

My files are in "PackageTmp".

```
 Content\C_C\ContinuousIntegration\_workspace\SolutionName\src\ProjectName\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\
```

How to remove them?

Comment: I noticed this as well and just lived with it, at the time a few years ago there didn't seem to be a way around it.  This seems fairly harmless as WebDeploy doesn't use these paths at all.  You'd need to modify the zip directory structure and I believe there was an XML file in there with internal paths.

Comment: I found a workaround, if I add "_PackageTempDir=C:\Package" I have the expected effect. it's cheating but it works :)